# How to exclude files from LTEX LanguageTool grammar/spell check

Tags: spellchecking

How can I exclude certain files from the grammar/spell check of [LTEX](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=valentjn.vscode-ltex) in VS Code?

It automatically scans all files in my project folder and finds about 100 errors in my bibliography.bib file for example.
My "Problems" tab is then full of those error messages and it gets confusing to find the real Latex compiling errors.

Comment: From the documentation it seems that a magic comment `% LTeX: enabled=false` at the start of the `.bib` file should work, see https://valentjn.github.io/ltex/advanced-usage.html#magic-comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Marijn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn) kindly posted as a comment, the answer is to use the magic comment `% LTeX: enabled=false` at the start of a file that should not be spell-checked. See [LTEX Magic Comments](https://valentjn.github.io/ltex/advanced-usage.html#magic-comments).

Sidenote: If errors should not be shown in the problems tab at all, just add `"ltex.diagnosticSeverity": "hint"` to the settings.json file. All errors will still be marked but won't be mentioned in the problems tab.